# Criar e manipular array com asp classic

Tags: asp, vbscript

Como criar, alimentar e ler o `array` com `key` e `value` usando Asp Classic?

preciso fazer algo mais ou menos assim.

```
$registro[] = array(
       "codigo"=> "$v",
       "municipio"=> "$v->municipio",
       "Rua"=> "$v",
       "Nome"=> "$v",
       "Sede"=> "$v",
       "Regional"=> "$v"
);
```

depois preciso de algo parecido com `foreach`

Alguém poderia ajudar?

Answer (score 6):

Para usar chaves e valores em ASP Clássico você tem o Dictionary:

```
Set registro = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
registro.Add "codigo", "12233"
registro.Add "municipio", "santo olavo"
...
```

Para iterar nos valores, você normalmente divide o dicionário em chaves e valores, e usa a propriedade "Count" para saber quantos ítens tem:

```
chaves  = registro.Keys
valores = registro.Items

For i = 0 To registro.Count - 1 'Lembre-se do -1, pois começamos de zero
  chave = chaves(i)
  valor = valores(i)
  Response.Write( chave & " => " & valor & "<br>")
Next
```

Ou mesmo:

```
For each chave in registro.Keys
    Response.Write( chave & " => " & registro.Item(chave) & "<br>")
Next
```

Answer (score 2):

Pode ser utilizado o [ASP Dictionary Object](http://webcheatsheet.com/asp/dictionary_object.php), o exemplo abaixo:

```
<%
    '//Criando o dicionário
    Dim d
    Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    '//Adicionando os itens
    d.Add "re","Red"
    d.Add "gr","Green"
    d.Add "bl","Blue"
    d.Add "pi","Pink"

    '//Recuperando e imprimindo valores
    dim a,c
    a = d.Keys
    c = d.items
    for i=0 to d.Count-1
        Response.Write(a(i) + " " + c(i))
        Response.Write("<br>")
    next
%>
```

Se ainda quiser imprimir com `For each` pode ser feito assim:

```
For each item in d.Keys
    Response.Write(item + " " + d.Item(item))
    Response.Write("<br>")  
Next
```

e para alterar algum valor, deve ser informado a chave e o novo valor, exemplo:

```
if (d.Exists("re")) then '// verificando se a chave existe        
    d.Item("re") = "new valor" '// alterando valores
end if
```

isso segue também o mesmo modelo para excluir, exemplo:

```
if (d.Exists("re")) then  '// verificando se a chave existe
    d.Remove("re") '// excluindo item 
end if
```

para remover todos os itens:

```
d.RemoveAll
```

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [ASP Dictionary Object](http://webcheatsheet.com/asp/dictionary_object.php)
- [Detect an a Dictionary Object in Classic ASP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9036857/detect-an-a-dictionary-object-in-classic-asp)
- [Dictionary Object](https://www.vbsedit.com/html/b4a7ddb3-2474-49ef-8540-8d67a747c8db.asp)